# Downloading PDF text into memory from GoogleCloudStorage using Langchain NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, google-cloud-storage, langchain-js

I Am trying to download a PDF file from a GCS storage bucket and read the content into memory.

When using Langchain with python, i can just use the GCSDirectoryLoader to read all the files in a bucket and the pdf text.

Langchain for NodeJs doesnt have GCSDirectoryLoader or a webloader for PDF files.
When downloading the file, i get a Document with the binary representation as content.

What is the best way to download pdf content from GCS bucket into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following for GCS bucket:

```
documentBucket.getFiles()
...

const [buffer] = await file.download();
const options = { normalizeWhitespace: true };

// Using 3rd part lib => pdf.js-extract
await pdfExtract.extractBuffer(buffer, options)
    .then((data) => {
      ...
    }
```

And for Google drive:

```
const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth,
  })

const resp = await drive.files.get({ fileId: file.id, alt: "media" }, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
const buffer = new Buffer.from(resp.data);
const options = { normalizeWhitespace: true };

// Using 3rd part lib => pdf.js-extract
await pdfExtract.extractBuffer(buffer, options)
    .then((data) => {
      ...
    }
```

The documentation for the API could be clearer, what I ended up needing was setting the responseType to 'arrayBuffer', which i couldn't find in the docs.

I'm still going to put some time into determening if the 3rd party lib is really needed... but that has a lower priority for me atm

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @K J

> anything can load into memory however to be of any usage for PDF handling the download needs to be a decimal addressed file (full length from position 0 to the end of FILE) and thus written with an end of FILE marker at /Length in decimalised numbers of bytes (thats how a PDF can file seek when working) so you need to either have or build a memory file system. Then the next process can read the file for conversion from filetype.pdf

Comment: I understand the concept, I was looking for a clear example of the correct syntax as i find the documentation to be lacking.

Comment: In the end, LangChainJs just doesn't have all the features that the python version has.